# Why did wife get 10% less miles than husband for same Amtrak trips?

Tags: loyalty-programs, amtrak

Why did wife get 10% less miles than husband for same Amtrak trips?
She's a senior citizen too.

```
On: 08/11/2022      On: 08/11/2022
Travel Earning      Travel Earning
46                  41

On: 08/10/2022      On: 08/10/2022
Travel Earning      Travel Earning
154                 139
```

And now it's past the 120 limit to get the points back.
Other trips earlier and later all had the same miles posted.
Maybe the husband qualified for some 10% bonus?
I asked Amtrak but they just sent me a form letter.

Comment: Were both tickets at the same price? Maybe she got the last seat at one price and yours was the next price up so resulted in more miles? Not sure if that can happen when the two trips are booked together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like many airlines today, Amtrak's loyalty program is fundamentally based on ticket price, not miles. Specifically, you receive [2 points per dollar](https://www.amtrak.com/guestrewards/ways-to-earn/amtrak-travel.html). You mentioned your wife is a senior citizen, which entitles her to a [10% discount](https://www.amtrak.com/seniors-discount). Because her ticket was 10% cheaper, she received 10% less points.

Note that the senior discount is not applicable with any other discount and certain premium seating. The other fares were likely ineligible for the senior discount.